# OBIEE Passing Parameter to Analysis With URL

Tags: oracle, url, business-intelligence, obiee

I have this Analysis that I wish to invoke from URL (which I can).

This analysis in particular is mounted on a dashboard and 6 of the 17 columns can be filtered from a prompt mounted on the same dashboard.

I only need the analysis and still be able to filter the results. I read about parameters that can be given to the URL, but I can't seem to make the filters work. I am using the `&P0=n` parameter and the consequent `&P1=xx` parameter.

Without the `&P` I am able to see the table, when I add parameters I get this error *UH6MBRBC:E6MUPJPH*.

Thanks for your time, have a nice day.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit more? Because the GoPath etc work perfectly fine. What is the exact call? What exactly do you pass? Did you chexk the generated URL? What is the actual error? That alphanumeric string doesnt say anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by myself afterall (always best).

Basically instead of `&p0` and such I used `&coln` and `&valn` (where `n` is the column number):

`&coln` - is the name of the field

`&valn` - is the value for which you filter

More information and better explanation can be found [here](https://obieeil.blogspot.it/2014/10/obiee-go-url-and-filter-parameters-old.html).